# License of a not anymore existing pip library

Tags: license

I think the question is language agnostic but we are doing an audit and there is a python library which doesn't specify license and it doesn't install anymore.

```
> pip freeze | grep MakeJS
MakeJS==0.0.3.3
```

so it's installed on production but when I try to install locally:

```
> pip3 install MakeJS==0.0.3.3
Collecting MakeJS==0.0.3.3
     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
MakeJS==0.0.3.3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MakeJS==0.0.3.3
```

- and the second question is forget about this library, what if someone publishes a piece of code on pip without specifying license, what are the conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a piece of software (be it a library or something else) does not specify a copyright license, then you must assume that the default "license" of "all rights reserved" applies.

This means that technically you are not allowed to make copies of the software, which also means you would not be allowed to install it.
If such a software package is made available in a standard package manager, then it can be argues that the author intended to give you a license to install the software, but not to do anything else with it that would be protected by copyright, like making changes or making a derived work.